# extending \widetilde in formula

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have the following code:

```
\widetilde{\text{trunc}(\Delta_\mathbf{tot}(X))}
```

and the output in codecogs is

[image]

How Can I do to extend \widetilde? How Can I do to have the following formula:

[image]

Comment: I showed a duplicate question, that also has answers; please, don't do that way: your readers will wonder what that blot over the formula means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need specialist fonts or do it via `tikz`. IMO it is better to have two syntaxes for this. Use the `\widetilde` for short expressions, and `\somename(trunc...)` for long ones. The very wide tilde will become very ugly.

BTW: it is not a good idea to use `\text{trunc}` as it does not do what you think. Better to use `\operatorname{trunc}` if it is a one of, or define `\trunc` via

```
\DeclareMathOperator\trunc{trunc}
```

(reason `\text{trunc}` is italic in an italic context, e.g., the body of a theorem)

Comment: Which code do you mean?